# Golang exec.Command

Tags: bash, golang, powershell

не могу понять как запустить команду (PowerShell) в linux из Go, просто в консоле запускаю так и все работает, а когда из Go то отображает сообщение как будто запустил команду без аргументов.

```
pwsh -Command 'Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -Port 25 -To testuser@localhost -From youremail@domain.com -Subject "This is a test email" -Body "test body"
// в консоле отправляется нормально
```

из Go:

```
pwsh = "pwsh"
command = "-Command 'Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -Port 25 -To " + recipient + " -From " + user.Email + " -Subject \"" + subject + "\" -Body \"" + message + "\"'"
output, err := exec.Command(pwsh, command).Output()
// result: как будто просто написал pwsh
```

Подскажите как запустить из Go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell принимает 2 (два) аргумента, а вы передаете один длинный. Передавайте каждый аргумент в отдельной строке:

```
output, err := exec.Command("pwsh", "-Command", "'Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer...").Output()
```